# Axios request with Contact forms 7

Tags: axios, contact-form-7

I'm using contact forms 7, and in my form submission I use this function:

```
  const formData = {
      'your-name':'John Doe',
      'your-email': 'johndoe@mail.com',
    }
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://0xsociety.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/258/feedback',
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
     data: formData,
   
    })
```

But it doesnt work, i get errors saying fields are empty.
But I tried with postman and it works perfectly when i do it manually

How would I get my axios post request to mimic this:

https://gyazo.com/e1ffe5bcc3f943a074d9b9e2c32b162d

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by using postman in my app:

```
import request from 'postman-request'

   const formData = {
      'your-name': name,
      'your-email': email,
      'your-subject': inquiries.find(x=> x.value === inquiry).text,
      'file-871': file
 }
    request.post('https://your-domain/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/your-form-id/feedback',{ form: formData}, function(err,httpResponse,body){
      if(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      else {
        console.log(body)
      }
    })
```